# SQL server 2012: Cast a varchar (255) column to datetime results to an out-of-range value error

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to read a column from tbl1 with type varchar(255) and load it to tbl2 as type datetime. See code below.

```
 SELECT CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(NLCompany)) AS varchar(20)) AS SRC_NLCompany, 
 CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(AccountCode)) AS varchar(8)) AS SRC_AccountCode, 
 CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(DocumentNumber)) AS numeric(10, 0)) AS SRC_DocumentNumber, 
 CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(PaymentType)) AS varchar(1)) AS SRC_PaymentType, 
 CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(PostingDaybkDate)) AS datetime) AS SRC_PostingDaybkDate
 FROM TBL1
```

Error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many string formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what language / dateformat settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server **2008** and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible